# Scanf Crash During Runtime

Tags: c, pointers, crash, runtime-error, scanf

The following code is to obtain input from the user and place it into the struct variables which are stored in an array of pointers. Depending on which program you use to run the code below it might or might not crash. I am currently using WinSCP and it doesn't give me an error but rather just crashes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Structure
{
    char character ;
    char* string ;
    int integer ;
    float floatingPoint ;
    
} Structure ;
    
void insertData(struct Structure *x)
{
    int i ;
    
    for (i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter a character: ") ;
        scanf(" %c", &x[i].character) ;
        
        printf("Enter an integer: ") ;
        scanf("%d", &x[i].integer) ;
        
        printf("Enter a string: ") ;
        scanf("%s", x[i].string) ;
        
        printf("Enter a floating point: ") ;
        scanf("%f", &x[i].floatingPoint) ;
    }
}

void printData(struct Structure *x)
{
    int i ;
    int count = 1 ;
    
    for (i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
    {
        printf("\nStructure %d:", count) ;
        count++ ;
        printf("\n\tPointer: %p\n", x[i]) ;
        printf("\tCharacter: %c\n", x[i].character) ;
        printf("\tInteger: %d\n", x[i].integer) ;
        printf("\tString: %s\n", x[i].string) ;
        printf("\tFloating Point: %.1f\n", x[i].floatingPoint) ;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i, count = 1;
    Structure* pointers = (Structure*) malloc(5 * sizeof(Structure)) ;
    for (i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
    {
        pointers[i].string = malloc(sizeof(char)) ;
    }
    
    insertData(pointers) ;
    printData(pointers) ;
    
    free(pointers) ;
    printf("\n") ;
    
    for (i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
    {
        printf("Structure %d pointer: %p\n", count, &pointers[i]) ;
        count++ ;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

To be more specific, it crashes when it reaches the line "scanf(" %c", &x[i].character) ;" with no exact error message.

Comment: Did you allocate memory for the string members?

Comment: Most likely you are passing an uninitialized pointer for Structure.  Also, Your InsertData routine says it returns `void *` but doesn't.

Comment: @EmanuelP I am allocating memory, everything works as intended in a different online compiler but not thorugh WinSCP.

Comment: @stark Code has been updated to include everything. Keep in mind, everything works as intended in a different online compiler so I believe everything else is correct

Comment: @Jon You only allocate memory for a single `char` per string. If the user enters anything more than 0 characters, scanf will cause a buffer overflow. This may go unnoticed sometimes, but that's a lucky shot.

Comment: @EmanuelP That's something that I thought was an issue as well. However, I used "malloc(999)" to test that theory earlier and it is still crashing. Moreover, how would I fix the issue of malloc without knowing the size of the string? Since the string is given after input

Comment: @Jan You shouldn't use `scanf` when you don't know the size of the input. Or if you do, specify a maximum size like so `scanf("%100s", x[i].string)` after you've allocated 100 bytes per string. However, you may want to look at `getline` instead.

Comment: @EmanuelP "scanf("%100s", x[i].string) after you've allocated 100 bytes per string" is off-by-one.  `"%99s"` is better.  Note: `getline` is not in the standard C library.

Comment: @chux Those off-by-one errors get me every time. `fgets` is an alternative that is in the standard C library. At least that requires you to be explicit about the buffer you have to allocate.

Comment: @EmanuelP I too had off-by-ones for years.  With `scanf("%99s"...`, what helped me was recalling 99 is a maximum input character _width_, not a _size_.

Comment: @EmanuelP ```fgets(x[i].string, 50, stdin) ;``` the following line is not working and instead it is skipping the string input, aka not asking for the input

Comment: `printf("\n\tPointer: %p\n", x[i]) ;` should use `&x[i]`

Comment: A very important fact to keep in mind: "everything works as intended in a different compiler" does not mean anything. Especially it does not mean that everything is correct. The other compiler might just hide your bugs better.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf("%s", x[i].string) ;` passes in an indeterminate value of `x[i].string` as that pointer is never assigned.

Various alternatives exist:

Simple alternative: change `Structure` to have an array member rather than a pointer.

```
typedef struct Structure {
  char character;
  // char* string;
  char string[100];
  int integer;
  float floatingPoint;
} Structure;


// scanf("%s", x[i].string);
scanf("%99s", x[i].string);
//            ^---------^--  &x[i].string[0] is passed to scanf   
//      ^^ ----------------  Use a width limit, one less than the size
```

Better code would check the return value of `scanf()`.

Other problems may exist (review lack of return value).  [@stark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67048603/scanf-crash-during-runtime/67048860#comment118514127_67048603)
Need calling code for further analysis.

---

With OP's additional restriction, code needs to allocate space for the string - more than 1.

Perhaps as simple as:

```
// Structure* pointers = (Structure*) malloc(5 * sizeof(Structure)) ;
Structure* pointers = malloc(sizeof *pointers * 5);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  pointers[i].string = malloc(100):
}
```

Better code would check allocation results and size the `.string` to the amount read.

---

Do not use `free(pointers) ;` after freeing

```
// free(pointers) ;  // Do not free yet
for (i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {
    // printf("Structure %d pointer: %p\n", count, &pointers[i]) ;
    printf("Structure %d pointer: %p\n", count, (void *) &pointers[i]) ;
    // Good code yses a cast here --------------^------^
    count++ ;
}
// Now OK to free
free(pointers) ;
```

Comment: It is a requirement that I use char* so therefore I cannot change the variable listed above, although I would love to. However, I updated the code and I included everything I wrote including how I assigned and declared the pointers.

Comment: @Jon Unexpected requirements like "requirement that I use char*" deserve to be stated in the initial question.

Comment: @Jon Who or what text suggested casting the return value of `malloc()` as in `(Structure*) malloc(5 * sizeof(Structure))`?

Comment: Not entirely sure, I am fairly new to C so I'm learning through the help of others and examples that have worked. Keep in mind when I run all the code under a different compiler and console, everything works properly and everything printed is listed properly

Comment: @Jon With `struct Structure *x .... printf("\n\tPointer: %p\n", x[i]) ;`, I doubt the veracity  of "everything works properly and everything printed is listed properly".  Save time, enable all warnings.

Comment: That's right, I changed that part of the code last minute, how would I print the address of the pointer? I wrote ```"printf("\n\tPointer: %p\n", &x[i])"``` however I don't see the address of the pointer change before and after I free the memory.

Comment: @Jon "however I don't see the address of the pointer change before and after I free the memory." is like saying I stole from a store and did not get caught, so it must be OK.  After a pointer is free'd, do not use it.

Comment: I am required to show the address before and after it is freed to see what exactly is supposed to happen when the address is freed. However, I can see that nothing is happening so I assume something is wrong. Would you like to move to a chat? I'll show u all of the exact requirements if you'd like.

Comment: "I am required to show the address before and after it is freed to see what exactly is supposed to happen when the address is freed" --> Is a poor assignment as it encourages _undefined behavior_.  Sorry your assignment is ill formed.

Comment: I wish it wasn't so ill formed but hey what am I gonna do about it? Gotta pass my class somehow! I am still just really confused as to why my compiler is crashing though, and as to why the pointer address is still the same before and after

Comment: @Jon "why the pointer address is still the same before and after" --> What were you expecting _after_?  Are you still doing `printf("\n\tPointer: %p\n", x[i])`?

Comment: @Jon What you are probably required to do by "showing the address before and after it is freed" is something like `char *ptr = malloc(99); printf("%p", ptr); free(ptr); printf("%p", ptr)` This is fine and will work. It will print the same both times. `ptr` still points to the same address, but the value at that address is no longer accessible.

Comment: @EmanuelP Attempting to print the free'd pointer is UB

Comment: @chux. No, it's not. The pointer is initialized and call the `free` doesn't change that. `printf` doesn't deference the pointer either. It is equivalent to `printf("%ux", (unsigned long)ptr)`

Comment: @EmanuelP I suspect your reasoning is based on your experience and not the C spec.  See [How can I print a dangling pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51344161/2410359)  `printf("%ux", (unsigned long)ptr)` is certainly UB as `ptr` no longer contains a valid value - the conversion is not defined (and I suspect you meant `"%lx"`).  `free()` changes the validity of the pointer.  Its subsequent use is not defined. If still not convinced, perhaps post a question.  A complier need not create the code you think it will with a dangling pointer.

Answer (score -1):

You are using pointer( `*` ) So Use( `->` ) instead of dot (`.`) You Will definitely Solve this problem.

```
scanf(" %c", &x[i] -> character);
```

Like wise....Do it.Thank You!

Comment: This is incorrect. The `[i]` is already dereferencing the pointer. Such a problem would also cause a failed compilation, not a runtime error.